# how to skip one batch and move to next batch to insert the record in sqlbulkcopy

Tags: sql-server

I use sqlBulkCopy to insert the data with BatchSize=10000 in fist 3 batch data are inserted sucessfully. the next batch can not
insert. because Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EventSummary41' Cannot insert duplicate key in object.The statement has been terminated
how to skip that particular batch and move to next batch to insert the record.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  these 2 option in bcp-

```
-f paramter to specifiy row no to start from
-d paramter to specifiy where to stop
```